# HLSL Shader Model 4: Is there a way to avoid pixel shader computing all code paths?

Tags: performance, hlsl

I have a pixel shader that needs to output either a plain colored pixel or a texel sampled from one of three textures - selected by a switch statement operating on an index fed in by the vertex shader:

```
// textures

tbuffer textures
{
    SamplerState                            sState;

    Texture2DArray                          system;
    Texture2DArray                          images;
    Texture2DArray                          render;
};

// input

struct ps_in
{
    float4                                  position    : SV_POSITION;
    nointerpolation float4                  color       : COLOR;
    nointerpolation uint                    atlas       : ATLAS;
    nointerpolation float                   slice       : SLICE;
    float2                                  texcoord    : TEXCOORD;
};

// shader

float4 main(ps_in input) : SV_TARGET
{
    [forcecase] switch (input.atlas)
    {
    case 1:
        return input.color * system.Sample(sState, float3(input.texcoord, input.slice));
    case 2:
        return input.color * images.Sample(sState, float3(input.texcoord, input.slice));
    case 3:
        return input.color * render.Sample(sState, float3(input.texcoord, input.slice));
    default:
        return input.color;
    }
}
```

It seems that the shader is computing all 4 code paths every time the shader is called. If there had been a way to make an array of `Texture2DArrays`, I could have indexed into it via the `input.atlas` variable and gotten rid of the switch, but apparently there isn't.

Each object in this system is a quad instance and the atlas is guaranteed to stay the same across each individual quad. Is there a better way to do this? The entire screen redraw has to be done in one draw call, so I cannot split this into 4 different pixel shaders.